# Why is this SQlite3 query execution returning "SQLITE BUSY : Database is locked" and what it the likely solution

Tags: c++, windows, sqlite, mfc

This code keeps returning "SQLITE BUSY : Database is locked" even though I was not accessing it from another external thread or process and how can I resolve this?

The code uses CppSQLite3 C++ wrapper for SQLite.

```
int DepartmentAccess::SaveOrDeleteAccess(long long iDeptNameID,long long &iUserID,int &iAccessTypeID)
{
    char szString[1000];
    char chAccessTypeID[1000];

    StringCbPrintfA(szString,sizeof(szString),"%d",iAccessTypeID);
    EncryptString(szString,chAccessTypeID);


    try
    {
        char szDatabaseFile[1000];
        GetDatabaseA(szDatabaseFile,sizeof(szDatabaseFile));

        CppSQLite3DB db;
        db.open(szDatabaseFile);

        CppSQLite3Statement stmt = db.compileStatement("SELECT AccessID FROM DepartmentAccess WHERE (InsututionID = ? AND DeptNameID = ? AND UserID = ? AND AccessType = ?)");
        stmt.bind(1,m_iInsututionID);
        stmt.bind(2,iDeptNameID);
        stmt.bind(3,iUserID);
        stmt.bind(4,chAccessTypeID);
        CppSQLite3Query q = stmt.execQuery();
        if(!q.fieldIsNull(0))
        {
            if(!m_iMode)
            {
                return -2;
            }
        }

        if(!m_iMode)
        {
            StringCbCopyA(szString,sizeof(szString),"INSERT INTO DepartmentAccess(InsututionID,DeptNameID,UserID,AccessType) VALUES(?,?,?,?)");
        }
        else
        {
            StringCbCopyA(szString,sizeof(szString),"DELETE FROM DepartmentAccess WHERE (InsututionID = ? AND DeptNameID = ? AND UserID = ? AND AccessType = ?)");
        }

        CppSQLite3Statement stmt1 = db.compileStatement(szString);

        int iPosition = 1;

        stmt1.bind(iPosition++, m_iInsututionID);
        stmt1.bind(iPosition++, iDeptNameID);
        stmt1.bind(iPosition++, iUserID);
        stmt1.bind(iPosition++, chAccessTypeID);
        //Execution gets to this point
        stmt1.execDML();
        //Execution fails to get to this point
        if(!m_iMode)
        {
            StringCbPrintfA(szString,sizeof(szString),"DELETE FROM DepartmentAccessRequest WHERE (InsututionID = ? AND DeptNameID = ? AND UserID = ? AND RequestedAccess = ?)");
            CppSQLite3Statement stmt2 = db.compileStatement(szString);
            int iPosition = 1;

            stmt2.bind(iPosition++, m_iInsututionID);
            stmt2.bind(iPosition++, iDeptNameID);
            stmt2.bind(iPosition++, iUserID);
            stmt2.bind(iPosition++, chAccessTypeID);

            stmt2.execDML();
        }
        return 1;
    }
    catch(CppSQLite3Exception & e)
    {
        char szString[200];
        StringCbPrintfA(szString,sizeof(szString),"Error Code: %d\n Error Mesage: %s",e.errorCode(),e.errorMessage());
        MessageBoxA(NULL,szString,"Save Or Delete Access Error(Department Access)",MB_OK);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you not have to cleanup queries?

Comment: I was of the opinion that stringcbprintf overwrites buffer content since it is not an append operation. Nonetheless I will make some alteration and see what happens.